# PHPExcel: Rows fuse together on a CSV Import

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to import CSV to a SQL base, i'm using Scriptcase CRM.

The importation process seems to kinda work... it echoes the sql input. The first line its ok, but in the second line, the first one fuses, on the thrid the second and first...etc.

```
NSERT INTO abonado_table (id_abonado,dn,nip,curp_id,cac_id, modelo_id,modalidad,canal_de_venta,folio_abd,status,envio,icc_virtual,encuesta,contacto_id,monto_probable_recarga,fvc_estimada,sim_fisico,recuperada_mdc,equipo_liberado,creado_usr,modificado_usr,creado_fecha,modificado_fecha) VALUES (DEFAULT,'3149902172','7777','102329','104','2060','Prepago','','','5','','','','16','60','2018-07-31','0','','No','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 13:47:00','2018-07-30 13:47:00');
...
INSERT INTO abonado_table (id_abonado,dn,nip,curp_id,cac_id, modelo_id,modalidad,canal_de_venta,folio_abd,status,envio,icc_virtual,encuesta,contacto_id,monto_probable_recarga,fvc_estimada,sim_fisico,recuperada_mdc,equipo_liberado,creado_usr,modificado_usr,creado_fecha,modificado_fecha) VALUES (DEFAULT,'3149902172','7777','102329','104','2060','Prepago','','','5','','','','16','60','2018-07-31','0','','No','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 13:47:00','2018-07-30 13:47:00''9311251885','8888','102330','104','4389','Prepago','','','5','{null}','','','17','60','2018-07-31','0','','Si','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 13:50:00','2018-07-30 13:50:00');
...
INSERT INTO abonado_table (id_abonado,dn,nip,curp_id,cac_id, modelo_id,modalidad,canal_de_venta,folio_abd,status,envio,icc_virtual,encuesta,contacto_id,monto_probable_recarga,fvc_estimada,sim_fisico,recuperada_mdc,equipo_liberado,creado_usr,modificado_usr,creado_fecha,modificado_fecha) VALUES (DEFAULT,'3149902172','7777','102329','104','2060','Prepago','','','5','','','','16','60','2018-07-31','0','','No','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 13:47:00','2018-07-30 13:47:00''9311251885','8888','102330','104','4389','Prepago','','','5','{null}','','','17','60','2018-07-31','0','','Si','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 13:50:00','2018-07-30 13:50:00''4157165854','7777','102331','253','484','Prepago','Especialista','','4','{null}','','','18','60','2018-07-31','0','','','admin','rosa.valenzuela','2018-07-30 0:00:00','2018-07-30 20:20:00');
...
```

Here's the code, whats wrong?

```
    $objReader  = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $xslpath = "/opt/NetMake/v9/wwwroot/import_xls/".{xsl_input};
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($xslpath);
    $worksheetData  = $objReader->listWorkSheetInfo($xslpath);
    $totalRows  = $worksheetData[0]['totalRows'];
    $totalColumns = $worksheetData[0]['totalColumns'];
    $lastColumn  = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
    $sheet   = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $rowDate  = "";

    for($row=1;$row<=$totalRows;$row++){
     for($column=0;$column<$totalColumns;$column++){
      if($column==$totalColumns-1){
       $rowDate.="'".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getValue())."'";

      }else{
       $rowDate.="'".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getValue())."',";
      }
     }

         echo "INSERT INTO abonado_table (id_abonado,dn,nip,curp_id,cac_id, modelo_id,modalidad,canal_de_venta,folio_abd,status,envio,icc_virtual,encuesta,contacto_id,monto_probable_recarga,fvc_estimada,sim_fisico,recuperada_mdc,equipo_liberado,creado_usr,modificado_usr,creado_fecha,modificado_fecha) VALUES (DEFAULT,".$rowDate.");<br />...<br />";
}
sc_alert($totalRows." registros agregados!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer. you got your string declaration in the wrong spot
Move

```
     $rowDate  = "";
```

between

```
for($row=1;$row<=$totalRows;$row++){
 for($column=0;$column<$totalColumns;$column++){
```

So it looks like

```
for($row=1;$row<=$totalRows;$row++){
 $rowDate = ""; 
 for($column=0;$column<$totalColumns;$column++){
```

Comment: That's it! i feel so dumb now, but Thanks!